# video (.mp4) stored on Amazon S3 starts to download instead of playing in the video player

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, amazon-s3

For my Rails CourseApp, I want to make videos files (.mp4) available that are stored in the database.

this is the link to my video, as it is stored in the database:

```
"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/courseapp/videos/sigkledij_eng_verun.mp4"
```

in my Rails view, the iFrame is defined as:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/courseapp/videos/sigkledij_eng_verun.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, when I try to watch this video in the video player, instead of playing, it starts to download.

The odd thing is that with another video file, accessed through Amazon's CloudFront, (it isn't one of my video's, it's just for testing purposes), it does start playing in the video player

Anyone familiar with this problem?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: found the issue. I had to change the content-type in my Amazon S3 Bucket (under properties > metadata) from application/octet-stream to video/mp4

Answer (score 4):

In the amazon S3 metadata settings, change the "Key: Content-Type" Value to "video/mp4" (without quotes).

It doesn't appear to be an option in the dropdown select list, but you can copy from here (or a text editor) and tab into the Value field to paste.

Comment: My video was playing in certain versions of firefox and in some other versions it was throwing error. Certainly it was a problem of content type. Solved it by passing the content type explicitly as s3_headers

Comment: Its playing If i change for particular object content type. But i would like implement for all video whichever I uploaded. How to do?

Comment: This answer helped a lot, Thanks guys, I was facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

try with `video_tag` instead of `iframe`...

refer to this

```
<video width="800" height="467" poster="media/example.png">
    <source src="<%= Rails.root+"/public/"+@video.source.url%>">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue tonight. There is no longer a "video/mp4" option for metadata but but selecting "audio/mpeg" also allows it to stream rather than download.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `Content-Type` to `video/mp4` may not be enough, you would need to also set `ContentDisposition` to `inline`